# PHP tags show as plain text inside HTML code

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a front end developer and I'm new to PHP. I'm building a contact form for my site using BootStrap3, while the form actually submits the message and I'm able to receive the sent message in my gmail inbox, some of the PHP tags show as plain text in the modal form. How do I make the error messages appear as text, instead of polluting the form with PHP tags?

The Boottrap3 form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?><!-- shows all the time as code-->
                </div>
             </div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?><!-- shows all the time as code-->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The PHP code (index.php)

```
<?php
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'Demo Contact Form';
    $to = 'demo@test.com';
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

// If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errName || !$errEmail || !$errMessage || !$errHuman) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add at least `if` condition before you display the paragraph containing error message, e.g.:

```
<?php if ($errName) : ?>
<p class="text-danger"><?php echo $errName ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It should do the trick in your example.

**And btw:** your contact form should be provided as a PHP file. If it's an HTML file, it wont work because it wont get interpreted by PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The contact form cant be PHP file because it's a part of bootstrap's modal window, which provides a "platform" to a contact form. I can actually send mails from my server, but the validation of the fields doesnt work yet, for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>".$errName."</p>";?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working. looks like the ?> tag is not recognized as a php tag, but as a text.

Comment: Yo should use Javascript or AJAX based validation for modal window. Try this plugin  [link](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator)